# How to deploy a static website on azure using Visual Code studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have been following [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/static-website/create-app) tutorial to develop and build a nodejs application.
When I use the command to build the package.json file, `missing script: build` error was coming. 
A possible solution to this is manually edit the "build" key:value pair in the package.json file, but I have no idea what to add in `value` part of it for building the webapp. 
Currently my package.json contains:
`{
  "name": "my-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo 'build script executed'"
 }
}`
After it, a folder named build should be there but it is not happening where all the html, css and js files will go.
All of the packages are upto date.
Running windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I also follow the tutorial you metioned.  I can build the webapp correclty on my side.
The build script: `react-scripts build`. For more detail information about Package.json please refer to my package.json.

**My Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-react-appp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

If you haven't installed the [Azure App Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice)extension , then you need to install it from  Visual Studio code  Marketplace. After that you could publish it to Azure webApp directly with VS code.

[image]